# Rosbag record to different path?

Tags: rosbag

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

Is there any way to record rosbag data to a different location than the default location?

I am getting the following error:

```
[ERROR] [1460470166.869390414]: Less than 1GB of space free on disk with corridorlocalization_2016-04-12-16-00-06.bag.active.  Disabling recording.
[ WARN] [1460470167.370142337]: Not logging message because logging disabled.  Most likely cause is a full disk.
```

Is it possible to record rosbag data to a pen drive?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/231741/rosbag-record-to-different-path?/) by [DanThe](https://answers.ros.org/users/24985/danthe/) on ROS Answers with karma: 47 on 2016-04-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The [rosbag](http://wiki.ros.org/rosbag/Commandline) wiki has the information. Assuming your pen drive is at `/mnt/pen` you can use either the `-o` or `-O` flag:

```
rosbag record -o /mnt/pen/ /chatter
rosbag record -O /mnt/pen/test.bag /chatter
```

The first case with lower-case `-o` will output a bag file with the timestamp at the location you specify. The second case with upper-case `-O` will output a bag file simply named `test.bag` at the location you specify (*without* the timestamp on the filename).

---

Originally posted by [Thomas D](https://answers.ros.org/users/304/thomas-d/) with karma: 4347 on 2016-04-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [DanThe](https://answers.ros.org/users/24985/danthe/) on 2016-04-14**:
Thanks for your answer!